# How to set up NIS client in Docker container?

Tags: docker, jenkins, nis

I am setting up a Jenkins master inside a Docker container.  The container runs on an Ubuntu 16.04 host, which itself is a virtual machine.

We use NIS for authentication in Jenkins, but **I cannot get the NIS client to run in the container.**  In my Dockerfile I replicated the [instructions for setting up NIS on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNISHowTo):

```
FROM jenkins
MAINTAINER John McGehee

# The base image set USER to jenkins
USER root

# Change user jenkins uid:pid from 1000:1000 to 7000:7000
RUN groupmod --gid 7000 jenkins
RUN usermod  --gid 7000 --uid 7000 jenkins

# Make user jenkins more convenient
RUN mkdir -p /home/jenkins
run chown jenkins:jenkins /home/jenkins
RUN usermod  --home /home/jenkins --shell /bin/bash jenkins --comment "Jenkins via Docker"

# Add user jenkins to group shadow so it can use NIS authentication
RUN usermod  --groups shadow jenkins

# Set up NIS clients per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNISHowTo
RUN echo '10.10.10.11   infra1 infra1.wavesemi.com infra1.wavecomp.com' >> /etc/hosts
RUN echo '10.10.10.12   infra2 infra2.wavesemi.com infra2.wavecomp.com' >> /etc/hosts

RUN apt-get update
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get install --yes portmap nis
RUN echo 'wavesemi.com' > /etc/defaultdomain

RUN echo 'portmap : 10.10.10.11' >> /etc/hosts.allow
RUN echo 'portmap : 10.10.10.12' >> /etc/hosts.allow

RUN echo '+::::::'   >> /etc/passwd
RUN echo '+:::'      >> /etc/group
RUN echo '+::::::::' >> /etc/shadow

RUN echo 'ypserver      infra1' >> /etc/yp.conf

RUN systemctl start nis

# Run user jenkins in container
USER jenkins
```

Then I ran the Dockerfile:

```
sudo docker build -t myjenkins .
```

The command `RUN systemctl start nis` gives the error:

```
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Unknown error -1
The command '/bin/sh -c systemctl start nis' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

but the rest of the Dockerfile runs successfully.

When I start the container, it knows only user `jenkins`, as defined in the container's `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: You can't meaningfully use `systemctl` if you're not running `systemd`, and the Jenkins container doesn't run `systemd`; it just runs Jenkins directly.  If you want to *also* another service inside the same container you're going to need to redesign things.

Comment: Indeed the Dockerfile is in a strange netherworld between the host and the container.  Thank you for your excellent comment @larsks on how running multiple services within a single container requires more thought.